# What's a maintainable way to determine if a value is set to its type's default value?

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have some code such as the following:

```
var someCollection = new int[] {};
var result = someCollection.SingleOrDefault();
```

I then want to determine if `result` was the default value. **However, I want to do so in a maintainable way so that if the element type of `someCollection` changes, the rest of the code doesn't require changing.**

The way this typically seems to be done (in a general sense) is `result == null`. In this case, of course, the type is not a reference type, so this won't work.

An improvement that avoids this assumption is `result == default(int)`. However, changing the element type would also require changing the argument to `default`, so the requirement of only changing the type in one place is still not met.

### Acceptance Criteria

1. Built-in logic is preferred over custom logic.
2. Elegant and concise code is preferred.
3. Efficient code is preferred. (For reference types, only a reference comparison should occur.)

Comment: And `default(type)` isn't very helpful if the default is a valid value. 0 for integers, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword. Since you don't know what the type will be, you can use generics.

```
public bool IsDefault<T>(T value)
{
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, default(T));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Stealing from Sam, and improving it:

```
public static bool IsDefault<T>(this T value)
{
    return value == null || value.Equals(default(T));
}
```

No need for a type check. The JIT will make it work because it knows what T is at JIT time.

> Note that if the type overrides Equals then it might say false even
>   when it is `default(T)` and it might say true even when it is not.
>   – commented by Eric Lippert

Comment: Yep, this works because comparing a value type with null always returns false.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Comparing a value of *non nullable value type* with null always results in false. Comparing a value of *nullable value type* with null can return true.

Comment: @usr: Note that if the type overrides Equals then it might say false even when it is default(T) and it might say true even when it is not.

Comment: @usr if you feel that another user's answer can be improved, feel free to improve (edit) it, instead of creating your (improved) copy. In this particular case, given your and Sam's rep difference it especially makes sense.

Comment: @zespri I cannot semantically alter his solution without his consent. That would be rude. My solution behaves differently. I copied the method signature for convenience, not because I was unable to produce it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work.

```
public static bool IsDefault<T>(this T value)
{
    var isValueType = typeof(T).IsValueType;

    if (isValueType)
        return value.Equals(default(T));
    else
        return value == null;
}
```

However, for value types, I figure this will call their overloaded `Equals` methods, which may or may not be a problem.